# Delete from the dictionary all dates before the day I chose

Tags: swift

I want to remove all dates before the day I choose, not including that day, but I can not do it. Thanks

```
var dictionaryTotal: [String:String] = ["2017 01 01":"153.23", "2017 01 02":"162.45", "2017 01 04":"143.65", "2017 01 05":"140.78", "2017 01 06":"150.23"]

let date = NSDate()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale

let TheStart = formatter.date(from: "2017 01 04")


for (key, value) in dictionaryTotal {

    var ConvertDates = formatter.date(from: key)

}
```

Comment: Use the provided structs by Swift to represent data (`Date` instead of `NSDate` in this case), unless there's a specific reason you need to use the other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also avoid DateFormatters altogether and compare by String value. In this specific case, it will work due to the formatting of the data you provided (`yyyy MM dd`).

```
let startDate = "2017 01 04"
let filteredDictionary = dictionaryTotal.filter({ (key, _) in key >= startDate })
print(filteredDictionary) //contains key value pairs for the keys 2017 01 04, 01 05 and 01 06
```

As previusly commented by Dávid, his solution is more generic but this one is much faster since it doesn't need to parse a Date on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` conforms to the `Comparable` protocol, so you can check if a given date occurs before your chosen date using the `<` operator. So it would look like this:

```
var newDictionaryTotal = dictionaryTotal
for (key, value) in dictionaryTotal 
{
    let date = formatter.date(from: key)
    if date < theStart {
        newDictionaryTotal.removeValue(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Both `date` and `theStart` are optionals though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` on a Dictionary.

```
var dictionaryTotal: [String:String] = ["2017 01 01":"153.23", "2017 01 02":"162.45", "2017 01 04":"143.65", "2017 01 05":"140.78", "2017 01 06":"150.23"]

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale

guard let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2017 01 04") else {fatalError()}
let filteredDictionary = dictionaryTotal.filter({ (key, value) in formatter.date(from: key)! >= startDate})
print(filteredDictionary) //contains key value pairs for the keys 2017 01 04, 01 05 and 01 06
```

Also make sure you conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lower-camelcase for variable names. Only use force unwrapping inside the filter is you are 100% sure all your keys will have the same format.

Comment: Or just use the String instead of parsing the date. In this specific case (due to the format) the String comparison will also achieve the same result. Not sure what's more efficient though, Date parsing or String comparison.

Comment: You're right, for this particular format even String comparison would work. However, since OP started off with a DateFormatter and that is the more generic solution, I chose to stick with it. Performance wise I am not sure either which would be better, but I guess since the data set has one key-value pair per day, it is unlikely to hit such a big number of elements for the performance to really matter.

Comment: `0.0131015833339916 s` (Date formatter solution) vs `0.000600666666286997` (String comparison)